Folder Redirection does not create Documents Folder
Windows Server 2016 environment, new deployment of RDS with folder redirection to a share on a file server.
Folder redirection is applied via GPO in user settings.
Configured settings for "Documents" (in fact for all folders) are
  Target: Advanced - specify location for individual user groups
  Settings: Grant the user exclusive rights - unchecked
            Move the contents               - unchecked
            Also apply redirection ...      - unchecked

Since no user has yet logged on, there would be no content to copy, so the above "should" make sense.
However, while it does create the desktop and start menu, the documents folder is not created. Downloads folder is not created either.
Curiously, it does create Pictures, Videos, Music folders.
Tried to check the "Move the contents ... " setting, but this does not change  the outcome.
What DOES work is to disable the GPO, let users log in without folder redirection, then have log everyone off, enable folder redirection with the "move the contents ..." option enabled for all folders. Then have the users log in again - and all folders exist and are properly redirected.
But this is super unworkable - this is a new deployment and I want redirection from the start.
There are many tutorials around and I have looked at many of them but none mentions this is as an issue.
Why is this happening, and how can I get the folder redirection properly work from the start with all folders including Documents appearing?

Here is what I found to solve this:

The GPO must be linked to the domain. It cannot be linked to the OU of the session host servers, or any other similar OU. Evidently Windows does not consider the policy applicable only to the session host servers.

When experimenting with user accounts login, before testing any change, you must not only delete the folders that got created by the login, but also the entire user profile disk (VHDX file). In Server 2016 and later, user profile disks are created by default, no matter whether folder redirection is used or not. Some settings related to these shell folders apparently get persisted there, in some way. Not removing the profile VHDX makes a change in the GPO not even apply.


With those two things out of the way, all of the folders were created properly for every user newly created.

If you link it to the server OU, but it's a user GPO, do you at least have loopback processing enabled on the servers?

Definitely a loopback issue. Also, Folder Redirection is a classic case of settings that are tatooed/persisted, that would explain the other part.
